# cxf memory leak? - large retained memory for responseContext

Tags: java, memory-leaks, cxf, cxf-client

(sorry, I'm very new to cxf so if I use the wrong terminology, please forgive me... corrections accepted!)

I have a cxf application that is used to accept data over the network.  I believe it is leaking memory as the heap size grows and is not released over time.  I have a jmap heap dump of the relevant object at https://i.stack.imgur.com/17vqc.png (sorry, cannot post images yet).

Has anyone experienced something like this, and if so, how should I go about solving this issue?  The huge memory consumption makes the application unusable over any medium length of time.

Thank you.

(I tried http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://javaetmoi.com/2014/02/memory-leak-client-cxf-attachment/&prev=search but this did not have any effect.)